# GitLab: How to include the previous job's artifacts as release assets?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

The task `create:release` creates a new release. How do we add the artifact `core.zip` in task `create:release`?

```
prepare:release:
  stage: prepare_release
  before_script:
    - echo "Setting up packages for Build"
    - apk --no-cache add zip
  script:
    - echo "Preparing release"
    - echo "Build Core"
    - yarn --cwd ./core/ install && yarn --cwd ./core/ build
    - echo "Zip distribution folder for Core"
    - zip -r core.zip ./core/dist ./core/node_modules ./core/package.json
  artifacts:
     paths:
       - core.zip
     expire_in: never

create:release:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  needs:
    - job: prepare:release
      artifacts: true
  variables:
    TAG: '$CI_COMMIT_SHA'
  script:
    - echo "Create Release $TAG"
  release:
    name: 'Release $TAG'
    tag_name: '$TAG'
    ref: '$TAG'
    description: 'Release $TAG'
```

Comment: Assuming the `release` stage is after the `prepare_release` stage, the `create:release` job should automatically have access to the artifact from `prepare:release` job. Try doing an `ls -la` command to the `create:release` job script

Comment: @Lukman That's right. The question is how to include them as release assets? Following the link https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#releaseassetslinks, each asset has attributes URL and filePath. What would be their values in this case when the assets are the job artifacts?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have resolved this. In `prepare:release` job, save the job id in an environment file and this file should be in the `artifacts.reports.env` of this job. Later, in the `create:release` job, use the API `"https://gitlab.com/<namespace>/<project_name>/-/jobs/<job_id>/artifacts/download"` to refer to the artifact.

Updated pipeline:

```
prepare:release:
  stage: prepare_release
  before_script:
    - echo "Setting up packages for Build"
    - apk --no-cache add zip
  script:
    - echo "Preparing release"
    - echo "Build Core"
    - yarn --cwd ./core/ install && yarn --cwd ./core/ build
    - echo "Zip distribution folder for Core"
    - zip -r core.zip ./core/dist ./core/node_modules ./core/package.json
  after_script:
    - echo "JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID" >> job.env
  artifacts:
     paths:
       - core.zip
     expire_in: never
     reports:
       dotenv: job.env

create:release:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  needs:
    - job: prepare:release
      artifacts: true
  variables:
    TAG: '$CI_COMMIT_SHA'
  script:
    - echo "Create Release $TAG"
    - echo $JOB_ID  
  release:
    name: 'Release $TAG'
    tag_name: '$TAG'
    ref: '$TAG'
    description: 'Release $TAG'
    assets:
      links:
        - name: "core.zip"
          url: "https://gitlab.com/<namespace>/<project_name>/-/jobs/$JOB_ID/artifacts/download"
```

Comment: on your last line, the release asset link url includes `<job_id>`. Is that something that's automatically substituted? It doesn't seem to be using your `job.env`.

Comment: @StealthRabbi A very good find. I have edited the answer now. `<job_id>` should be `$JOB_ID` which comes from the environment variables of the job `prepare:release`

Comment: @VishnuNadhan According to [Predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), we could use `$CI_PROJECT_PATH` instead of `<namespace>/<project_name>` and `$CI_JOB_ID` instead of `$JOB_ID`. (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: Use `$CI_JOB_URL/artifacts/download` as shortcut for the url

Comment: @Matej You can't use CI_JOB_ID because it will be set to the release's job id, however, we want to reference the job id of the build task (or prepare:release) and reference it's artifacts, hence we have to store the job id in a textfile which is retrieved by the release job.

Answer (score 1):

i couldnt work with the gitlab-ci key words for relase cli so i used release cli shell script and i resolved my issue like below:

```
create_tag:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  when: manual
  stage: create_tag
  #  before_script:
  #    - curl -L --output /usr/local/bin/release-cli "https://release-cli-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/release-cli-linux-amd64"
  #    - sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/release-cli
  #    - release-cli -v
  script:
    - ANGULAR_VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
    - echo running release_job for $ANGULAR_VERSION
    - export GODEBUG="x509ignoreCN=0"
    - docker save -o nmsclientwebangularV$ANGULAR_VERSION.tar $NEXUS_URL/admin/nmsclientwebangular:V$ANGULAR_VERSION
    - echo $CI_JOB_ID
    - release-cli --insecure-https create --name="Release V$ANGULAR_VERSION"  --tag-name="V$ANGULAR_VERSION" --assets-link='{"name":"DockerFile","url":"https://gitlab.sinacomsys.local:9191/nms/Access/NMSClient/nmsclient_web_angular/-/jobs/'$CI_JOB_ID'/artifacts/download?file_type=archive"}'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - nmsclientwebangular*.tar
  only:
    - master
```

in last line of script section i create release tag with release cli shell commands and i used **CI_JOB_ID** of this job.be careful to use it like this '$CI_JOB_ID';

if you want to use another job artifact you should save that job CI_JOB_ID in a custom variable like this:

```
export JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID
```

and then use **JOB_ID** instead of **CI_JOB_ID**

Answer (score 0):

```
  generate_executables:
  image: $IMAGE_SOURCE/python:3.7

  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - echo $CI_JOB_ID
    - echo GE_JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID >> generate_executables.env
    - echo GE_JOB_URL=$CI_JOB_URL>> generate_executables.env
  script:
    - echo "start running deploy_artificts"
    - echo "running deploy_artificts successfully"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fileXXX
    expire_in: 1 week
    reports:
      dotenv: generate_executables.env

release:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  needs:
    - job: generate_executables
      artifacts: true
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
  before_script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG_MESSAGE
  script:
    - echo "running release_job"
    - echo 'Previous Job ID is printed below'
    - echo $GE_JOB_ID
    - echo $GE_JOB_URL
    - release-cli --insecure-https create --name="$CI_COMMIT_TAG" --description "$CI_COMMIT_TAG_MESSAGE" --tag-name="$CI_COMMIT_TAG" --assets-link='{"name":"collect.zip","url":"'$GE_JOB_URL'/artifacts/download?file_type=archive"}'
```

Comment: here is the cocument https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/release_cli.html

Comment: You can edit your post if you have things (like a helpful link) to add to your answer. Also, as a general rule, it's best to explain the code you wrote in an answer. Making it more likely others understand (and upvote) your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully familiar with the artifacts in a pipeline, but the create:release job should get the artifacts from the prepare:release job by it's needs declaration. So the create:release job should be able to access the artifacts from previous prepare:release job and be able to declare the same artifacts as own one with the expire of never, so you would have the job id of your current job, the stored artifacts of the current job and can set the link to it. In the previous prepare:release job the expire I would set to 1day. So no need would be to transfer the job id from prepare:release to create:release?

Comment: Now I've reviewed this with my new knowledge and would change the pipeline in that way:

```yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

With my new knowledge I would change the pipeline in that way:

```yaml
prepare:release:
  stage: prepare_release
  before_script:
    - echo "Setting up packages for Build"
    - apk --no-cache add zip
  script:
    - echo "Preparing release"
    - echo "Build Core"
    - yarn --cwd ./core/ install && yarn --cwd ./core/ build
    - echo "Zip distribution folder for Core"
    - zip -r core.zip ./core/dist ./core/node_modules ./core/package.json
  artifacts:
     paths:
       - core.zip
     expire_in: 1 hour

create:release:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  needs:
    - job: prepare:release
      artifacts: true
  variables:
    TAG: '$CI_COMMIT_SHA'
  script:
    - echo "Create Release $TAG"
  artifacts:
     paths:
       - core.zip
     expire_in: never
  release:
    name: 'Release $TAG'
    tag_name: '$TAG'
    ref: '$TAG'
    description: 'Release $TAG'
    assets:
      links:
        - name: "core.zip"
          url: "https://gitlab.com/<namespace>/<project_name>/-/jobs/$CI_JOB_ID/artifacts/download"
```

In that way you can use the current `CI_JOB_ID` for the download link of artifacts, see the `expire_on` in the `prepare:release` part and in the `create:release`.